# How do I use escape characters in vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, web, escaping

I want to build a website similar to codepen.
I made a library with assets (buttons, cards, effects...), and I am building it with vue.js.
Each asset contains html code, css code and if necessary js code. I also want to format that code, and in vanilla js I did that with escape characters (\n, \t).
Unfortunately, this does not work in vuejs.

It sounds weird, but the output should be formatted html code.
This is an example of a string vanilla js that did work:

```
'<button class="btn">Button 1 - Red hover effect</button>\n<button class="btn">Button 1 - Red hover effect</button>';
```

And this is the output:

```
<button class="btn">Button 1 - Red hover effect</button>
<button class="btn">Button 1 - Red hover effect</button>
```

I want to build the same thing, but with vue.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: This is what v-html is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) api

Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS attacks. Only use v-html on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

Comment: And will the output be pure html

Comment: Because I still want html as output